# I'm having an issue with the layouts on my application and the way they are shown?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

This is my Homepage of my application(a work in progress). When I open my navigation drawer and navigate to my Media Page with tabbed fragments. As The Media Main page is an activity, without effecting the Navigation Drawer I manually had to enter the Navigation drawer into my XML Layout.

The issue is when I use the navigation drawer whilst my media page is open, the new fragment that I go to is not displayed properly. It is displayed just totally black.

***This is the Homepage that I want that appears when the app opens***
[image: The Home Page which I want to appear]

This is the Homepage that appears after I leave the Media Main Activity
[image]

Here is my Java Code below:

```
public class media_main extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ViewGroup container;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.media_main_fragment);
        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (findViewById(R.id.tabs) != null)

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
                return;


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ViewGroup mContainer = container;

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Drift Fan");
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.Home:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home Fragment");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.my_account:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new myAccountFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Account");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_about:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new AboutDriftingFragment());
                        findViewById(R.id.tabs).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("About Drifting");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_shop:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ShopFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Shop");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_media:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ShopFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Shop");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                }


                return false;
            }

            private void finish(media_main media_main) {
            }

        });




        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_media_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_media_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    media_gallery tb1 = new media_gallery();
                    return tb1;
                case 1:
                    media_video tb2 = new media_video();
                    return tb2;
                case 2:
                    media_podcasts tb3 = new media_podcasts();
                    return tb3;

            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Gallery";
                case 1:
                    return "Video";
                case 2:
                    return "Podcasts";
            }
            return null;
        }}
}
```

And here is my XML Code Below:

***fragment_media_main***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".media_main$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***media_main_fragment***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".media_main"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:background="@color/splash"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/splash"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/splash"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"


        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#000"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="#fff"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header">


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue

Comment: No I did not resolve